# My app shutdown without message only in iOS?

Tags: codenameone

This issue is only in iOS. My app crashes at PriceMap.put(id, PL) after putting 5-6 numbers of PL lists without any message. My app runs on Android and the simulator without any problem.

```
private static Map<Long, List<Obj_Price>> PriceMap = null;
    public static void reset(){
    if (PriceMap==null){
        synchronized(PC.class){
            try {
                instance = new PC();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
        return;
    }
    List<Long> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Long id:PriceMap.keySet()){
        priceList.add(id);
    }
    PriceMap = null;
    PriceMap = new HashMap<>();
     
    List<Obj_Price> PL;
    Long oid;
    for (int i=0; i<priceList.size(); i++){
        oid = priceList.get(i);
        try {
            PL = DBS.objPriceDAO.getHisPrice(oid);
            if (PL!=null){
                PriceMap.put(oid, PL);                        
                PL = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I notice the catch block is commented out, that might include a clue of what went wrong. In general an empty catch block is a huge problem, you should always use `Log.e(ex)`.

Comment: How do I get the log result?

Comment: I eliminated the code for sending emails to me. } catch (Exception ex) { updateTag = "scheduleTasks－DBS.reload()－restart －loadPriceMap－Error:"+ex.getMessage(); ServerAccess.htmlMail("daniel@XXXX.XXXX", startTime+" "+updateTag, ""); } It doesn't run to catch block but crashes at PriceMap.put(id, PL);

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is a memory crash but typically this would be written to the console if you can look at the crash log on the device that might provide you some clues.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to show the error in a `ToastBar`

Comment: The problem is my app crashed without any error message.

Comment: There might be a problem with the way iOS  handles `Long` & `Double` data types. I had similar problem when I tried to parse String data type to double and compare it to a double eg. the following comparison worked in Android & simulator but failed in iOS without any error: `if(Double.parseDouble("4.67887") == 4.67887) { //do something }` Note string being parsed to double was being obtained from a String array

Comment: I resolved this by converting both to String before comparing eg. `if(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("4.67887")).trim().equals(String.valueOf(4.67887).trim())){ //do something } `

Comment: @DanielTsai but does it have a crash log? You can see them on the device in newer iDevices and they can include interesting information about the error.

Comment: @Shai Almog. Thank you. I think is a memory shortage problem. I switched on the include source tag. And run the app on Xcode without any problem.

Comment: @DanielTsai Did you run it on a device in xcode? Notice that the simulator is far more flexible, if you can run it with a cable on the device you might be able to reproduce the crash in xcode.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I will try to do it.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I run code on the device. Please refer to the question.

Comment: This confirms that this is indeed a memory leak. Try running with the memory profiler in xcode. This should show the problem even in the simulator. If it isn't clear then post the screenshots/stacks from the memory profiler and we can review them together.

Comment: Run my app connecting cable to iPhone 7 Plus with the memory profiler in Xcode on a virtual machine. A lot of memory leaks. The output screenshot in question. However, my app failed to update the data. It didn't crash.

Comment: Sort by count and look at the top. Notice that there's a leak of `Double` values which I assume relates to this. It could be a false positive because the GC might still clean this all up. But when you point at this leak, it should show you the stack that allocated it. Are there others that are this big?

Comment: I would try to identify the point at this leak. But the source code is generated by cn1. How do I know how to revise my Java code in my cn1 project?

Comment: Fail to retrieve server data while running my app connecting cable to iPhone 7 Plus. So my app doesn't crash. I have sorted the count field. Pls. refer to question. I found memory leaks in CFData. Is that possible I don't release ConnectionRequest properly? Also add code for connection requestion request.

Comment: You would recognize the names of your own classes/packages in the stack traces e.g. in the screenshots you see `com_codenameone` in the frames. This can help point at the area that's problematic. I don't see anything big in this output and didn't see something major in your code unless the response data is huge.  Why is it failing to connect when debugging with a cable? Do you get an applicable error?

Comment: It is weird that my app has never crashed when I profile it connecting to iPhone 7 Plus.
My app runs very slowly when it's under profiling then the Mac crashes. My app did not crash and update successfully. Is it possible that Garbage Collector has enough time to collect memory so my app doesn't crash? I took a screenshot on Mac before it crashed attached to the question. The screen of the Mac flickers before it crashed

Comment: Odd. You can try adding an occasional `System.gc()` but that's a very poor workaround. Are you sure it's that loop that is at fault? If so, what does `DBS.objPriceDAO.getHisPrice(id)` do? Is a UI update triggered in a loop or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I have additional codes that send emails to myself so I know the line that crashes. I attached the codes to the question. I think there is no UI update in the loop.

Comment: Great, this raises several potential problems. sqlite is different between Android and iOS. It is far more sensitive to multiple threads working on the data and leaks far more. Do you always access the database from the same thread? I see you closed the cursor  with every loop, try keeping it open for the loop and closing it when you're finished. This might be thrashing sqlite.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Do you mean I can't close the cursor in fetchAll function? Would you post documents for standard procedure to process SQLite in iOS?

Comment: I mean, I want to narrow down the root cause. Closing and reopening the cursor will slow down the SQL and might increase the chance to a problem. The biggest problem is multiple threads accessing the DB concurrently, that crashes iOS and it is documented somewhere if I recall correctly.

Comment: Can I execute another query if I don't close and reopen the cursor? For example, I don't execute cursor.close() and use the same cursor to execute another query.

Comment: You're right. That was totally stupid of me. You need to close the cursor. Can you tell me how many queries you're executing in this loop? If it's an excessive number it might be chocking the system before the GC has time to run (native objects don't trigger GC). Also, can't you just collect all the dates and use a single query like:

`select obj_id, ddate, his_price from XXXXXXXXXX_price where obj_id = ? OR obj_id = ? or obj_id = ? order by ddate`

Then set all the IDs? One query.

Comment: There are only 5-6 queries in the loop, but every query returns about 2,000~4,000 Obj_Price objects. I will try your single query suggestion. Also, I will try to run the query in a single thread. Can I have queries in muti-thread concurrently but use synchronized for only one thread to run the query?

Comment: We tried synchronizing in the past and it didn't work well. This is a huge problem in iOS and might be the reason for these failures. In the past I built a version of the DB that does that implicitly (every query would go to a single thread dedicated to the DB and return the result) but this didn't work for some reason.

Comment: The code in question runs in a single thread and always crashes at PriceMap.put(id, PL).  Is that possibly related to DBS.objPriceDAO.getHisPrice(id)?

Comment: After collecting data using a single query, my app still crashes after running the updating process multiple times. My app crashes randomly and more frequently. I think it is because my app runs more time at PriceMap.put(id, PL); 
I declare and allocate PriceMap:
    private static Map<Long, List<Obj_Price>> PriceMap = null;
    PriceMap = new HashMap<>();

Comment: The question is if there's other code that might access the DB (even a different table) using a different thread. If it could crash in the IDE we would be sure as we would see the exact line and reason, since that doesn't happen this is all speculative. But I think I have an idea...

Comment: I have access to the DB using multi-thread at the start of my app process and finishes before the updating process but never crashes. My app only crashes in the updating process(codes in question). I have checked the profile there are only a few memory leaks after start my app.

Comment: I removed all the code about the thread. My app still crashed at the updating process without any message in iOS.

Comment: My app stores a lot of historical data in memory for showing in charts and calculating financial data. It needs to reload all the data and refresh charts after requesting data from the server in the updating process. My app always crashes at reloading data in the updating process or lags after the updating process. I think the memory allocated in charts or data may not freed after the updating process. It may be a memory deficit problem. How do I free a form? Can I set the form to null to free the form and recreate it after the updating process?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be broken:

```
List<Obj_Price> PL;
for (Long id:PriceMap.keySet()){
    try {
        PL = DBS.objPriceDAO.getHisPrice(id);
        if (PL!=null){
           PriceMap.put(id, PL);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //send ex.getMessage
    }
}
```

Notice you're iterating over the `PriceMap` yet changing it while iterating. This should through a `ConcurrentModificationException` but that is either swallowed or it doesn't happen since `keySet` is a copy of the `Map`. I'm guessing exceptions are thrown until the VM chokes.

Try:

```
Set<Long> keys = new HashSet<>(PriceMap.keySet());
for (Long id : keys){
    ...
}
```

My other suggestions in the comments about unifying the SQL and verifying single thread access also apply regardless.

Comment: I have tried the way like your answer but with a List. Pls. refer to the question.
It doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed a bug in the for loop I still had your original code there. Is that still a problem? I'm pretty low on ideas at this point, I'll need a way to reproduce this to help.